# Login a WP user via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, authentication, request

I have two websites:

- site.com (WordPress site)
- subdomain.site.com (another site)

I want to login a WP user in site.com (WP) from subdomain.site.com using WP REST API.

So, I do the following in functions.php in site.com (WP):

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('xxx/v1', '/login', [
        'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback'  => function (WP_REST_Request $request) {
            // I try this:
            wp_set_current_user(1);
            wp_set_auth_cookie(1);

            // and this:
            $user = wp_signon([
                'user_login' => 'xxx',
                'user_password' => 'xxx',
                'remember' => true,
            ], false);
        }
    ]);
});
```

And in subdomain.site.com, I use CURL to make the request.

Unfortunately, it doen’t work. The code is well executed but user login does not work, cookies are not defined.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );

function register_api_hooks() {
  register_rest_route(
   'xxx/v1', '/login',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'login',
    )
  );
 }

function login($request){
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $request["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
      echo $user->get_error_message();

     return $user;
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Comment: No errors. The code works outside REST API but not in.